# How can I check if my AVPlayer is buffering? for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I want to detect if my AVPlayer is buffering for the current location so that I can show a loader or something. But I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for AVPlayer. 
I am using this code but it's not working :

```
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .New, context: nil)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .New, context: nil)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: .New, context: nil)

override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if object is AVPlayerItem {
        switch keyPath {
            case "playbackBufferEmpty":
               // Show loader

            case "playbackLikelyToKeepUp":
                // Hide loader

            case "playbackBufferFull":
                // Hide loader
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was also stuck with this issue for months and today i found this article and my problem solved.I was using Swift 4 and iOS 12 as Base SDK. [Very HelpFul Article For Solving Buffering and Show Loader/Hide Loader](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-set-up-video-streaming-in-your-app-with-avplayer-7dc21bb82f3) This is working in Swift 4.

Comment: @user9438383 There is nothing in the above link.